# How to open this box in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

This box has opened accidentally in Microsoft Word and could not be closed.

How is this box opened and how can it be closed?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you specify the office version?

Comment: It seems to be a content Control box with some fields. Can you select and right-click it to get a menu to help us clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have somehow invoked Word's Cover Page feature. You'll find it on the left in the Insert ribbon (I've got Word 2016, but it was there in Word 2010, I recall). I tried it and disliked the lack of control I had with the result. I cannot remember how I removed it, but I can't remember it being difficult.

Good luck

{I think MS keeps telephone sanitisers busy during the day by making them invent useless features (like Cover Page) for MS office guaranteed to look good in a marketing video, but only of use once every three years for most people, but loved dearly by as many as five people in the USA. It was a similar group in Mercedes or BMW who invented the sensor allowing you to wave your shoe beside the exhaust to open the boot lid.)